# Will Changing Google Sheet name unlink previously linked Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet Fed by Multiple Google forms.

After building everything I realized that I need to change the sheet name.

Will changing the sheet name unlink all the forms that are currently feeding it?

thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, both the spreadsheet and particular tabs can be renamed as you need!